# Break after Marginnote?

Tags: marginnote

I'm trying to have the content continue after the margin note.  I don't care that there will be a huge gap in the content, I don't want the margin note to overlap.
Here's the result:
[image]

Here's the MWE I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,right=95mm,top=20mm, left=25mm, marginparwidth=75mm}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\marginnote{\blindtext \blindtext}[0cm]
\blindtext\\
\marginnote{\blindtext \blindtext}[0cm]
\blindtext 
\end{document}
```

Here's what I'm looking for:
[image]

Is this possible with Marginnote?  Is there a away to do this without tables?

Comment: Probably you could use a package dedicated to typesetting parallel text, such as the `paracol` package?

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at it right now.
So, when I use it I have to \switchcolumn at the beginning of any section, and then subsequently I have to use \switchcolumn* within each section to get the vertical alignment right.  I'll have to play with it when I get back to work Monday, but it does look promising.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using the `paracol` package. I have also used the `\columnratio` command in order to make le right column narrower. Without this command, both columns would be equally wide:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,right=25mm,top=20mm, left=25mm}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{14pt}
\columnratio{0.6}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\switchcolumn
\blindtext \blindtext

\switchcolumn*

\blindtext
\switchcolumn
\blindtext 
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```